# how to change colours in predefinite theme

Tags: beamer

Bonjour,

I desesperately try to change the colour of `\insert(short)part` in CambridgeUS theme.

Here is what I want:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{%
        author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{%
        section in head/foot}%
      \insertpart%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{%
        part in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{%
        date in head/foot}%
      \insertsubsection%
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

But whatever the `\setbeamercolor` I use, the fg colour for `\insertpart` (or `\insertsection`...) remains red!

For instance, I can change the bg colour:

```
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=green,bg=black}
```

the background becomes black the the foreground (for `\insertpart`) remains red and is not turned into green!

Does anybody have an answer and a reference where this is documented?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Check out the [Beamer Manual](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). Part 3 is dedicated to "changing the way things look."

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour. Your code works for me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=green,bg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{%
        author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{%
        section in head/foot}%
      \insertpart%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{%
        part in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{%
        date in head/foot}%
      \insertsubsection%
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\begin{document}

\part{Test Part}
\section{Test Section}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you must be careful; changing `palette tertiary` will affect other elements of the theme besides the `headline` (as can be seen in my example). If you want to change only the colors used in the `headline`, then you need to proceed in another way (setting the appropriate colors for the corresponding `beamer` boxes, for example).

Comment: The culprit has been found: in \hypersetup command, to feed the metadata, colorlinks=true override the changes made on colours for hyperlinks and \insertpart is a hyperlink... (similarly, you cannot change colours of items in toc)