# How do I change the background color of a footer in beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, color, backgrounds

I know just enough about `beamer` to be a danger to myself.  I am trying to change the color of a footer in `Boadilla` and am struggling.

First, I have declared

```
\usecolortheme[named=black]{structure}
```

so that I get black text for frame titles.  (Probably neither necessary nor terribly elegant.)

I would like the background of the footer to be a light blue with a yellow `\hrule` across the top.  I am using the following code:

```
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[color=blue, wd=\paperwidth,ht=1in,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\hfill\insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber{}
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

I can't seem to make the background color change.  Any help available?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you seen this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71016/how-to-change-colours-in-predefinite-theme/71022 or this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48804/beamer-background-color-for-footline or this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68587/how-to-change-colors-in-beamer-theme?

Comment: The leads to the previous questions were very helpful.  Here is the code that ended up working, in the hopes that it helps someone else further down the road:

Answer (score 3):

The leads to the previous questions were very helpful.  Here is the code that ended up working, in the hopes that it helps someone else further down the road:

```
\definecolor{ilpablue}{rgb}{0.16,0.43,0.75}
\definecolor{ilpayellow}{rgb}{0.86,0.69,0.13}
\setbeamercolor{footlinecolor}{fg=white,bg=ilpablue}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{{\color{ilpayellow}\hrule height 0.5pt width \paperwidth}}

\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
\textcolor{ilpayellow}{\hrule}
  \footnoterule
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.25in,dp=1ex,center]{footlinecolor}
    \hfill{\normalsize ILPA  WEBCAST  SERIES} \hfill
    \insertframenumber{}
    \vskip0pt plus.5fill
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

That code block pretty much exactly replicates the logo I was given.